Nuxt generate hangs on ci/cd
I'm working with a legacy website Nuxt.JS 2 that used to be built on Cloudflare, but now it's not possible (due to high memory consumption). Increasing memory with --max_old_space_size doesn't work, more memory is consumed than the Cloudflare builder can offer. Here is my nuxt.config.js:
require('dotenv').config()
const storyblokVersion = process.env.STORYBLOK_VERSION
const storyblokToken = process.env.STORYBLOK_TOKEN
if (!storyblokToken) {
  console.error('Missing Storyblok access token, probably missing .env file')
}

console.log('Starting Nuxt configuration...')
// eslint-disable-next-line nuxt/no-cjs-in-config
const timestamp = Date.now()
export default {
  server: {
    // host: '0', // default: localhost
  },
  vue: {
    config: {
      devtools: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production',
    },
  },
  env: {
    defaultLocale: 'de',
    dev: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production',
    isNotDraft: process.env.STORYBLOK_VERSION !== 'draft',
    storyblokToken,
    storyblokVersion,
    buildVersion: process.env.BUILD_VERSION,
    base_url_ch: process.env.BASE_URL_CH,
    turnstileSitekey: process.env.TURNSTILE_SITE_KEY,
  },
  dev: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production',
  debug: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production',
  mode: 'universal',
  target: 'server',
  loading: {
    color: '#0033FF',
  },
  head: {
    title: '....',
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      { name: 'theme-color', content: '#ffffff' },
      { name: 'msapplication-TileColor', content: '#000000' },
      {
        name: 'google-site-verification',
        content: ' ',
      },
    ],
    link: [
      ...
    ],
    script: [
      process.env.STORYBLOK_VERSION === 'draft'
        ? {
            type: 'text/javascript',
            src: '/tailwind.js',
          }
        : {},
      ....
    ],
  },
  hooks: {
    'generate:before': (generator, generateOptions) => {
      console.log(`Started generation!`)
    },
    'generate:routeCreated': (route, path) => {
      console.log(`Generated route: ${route} at path: ${path}`)
    },
    'generate:page': ({ route, setPayload }) => {
      console.log(`Started route: ${route} at payload: ${setPayload}`)
    },
    'generate:routeFailed': ({ route, errors }) => {
      console.log(errors, route)
      throw new Error(`The route '${route}' failed to generate. ${errors[0].error}`)
    },
  },
  router: {
    middleware: ['setCacheVersion', 'settingsLoader'],
    scrollBehavior: (to) => {
      if (to.hash) {
        return false
      }

      return { x: 0, y: 0 }
    },
  },
  i18n: {
    vueI18nLoader: true, // ENABLES LOCAL INTERNALIZATION
    silentFallbackWarn: true,
  },
  buildModules: ['@nuxtjs/eslint-module', '@nuxtjs/global-components', '~/modules/dynamicRoutes'],
  markdownit: {
    injected: true,
    use: [
      'markdown-it-attrs',
      'markdown-it-div',
      '@gerhobbelt/markdown-it-link-attributes/index.js', // don't remove index.js !!!
    ],
  },
  modules: [
    '@nuxtjs/dotenv',
    '@nuxt/http',
    '@nuxtjs/svg',
    '@nuxtjs/markdownit',
    [
      'storyblok-nuxt',
      {
        accessToken: storyblokToken,
        cacheProvider: 'memory',
      },
    ],
    ...storyblokToken.
  ],
  generate: {
    concurrency: 1,
    fallback: false,
    crawler: false,
    interval: 2000,
  },
  css: ['~assets/css/main.css'],
  plugins: ['~/plugins/sentry.js', '~/plugins/v-click-outside.js', '~/plugins/vuelidate.js'],
  build: {
    babel: {
      plugins: ['@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining', '@babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator'],
    },
    extractCSS: true,
    postcss: {
      plugins: {
        'postcss-import': {},
        'postcss-nested': {},
      },
    },
    extend(config, ctx) {
      config.resolve.alias.vue = 'vue/dist/vue.common'
    },
    transpile: ['vue-agile'],
  },
}

My custom module ~/modules/dynamicRoutes:
export default async function dynamicRoutes() {
  console.log('Starting dynamic routes generation...')
  console.log('Fetching cache version...')
  ...
}

My Github Actions Workflow:
name: Build and Deploy to Cloudflare Pages

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - stage  # or your production branch
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build-deploy:
    runs-on: self-hosted
    timeout-minutes: 40

    env:
      NODE_OPTIONS: --max_old_space_size=750000
      ACTIONS_STEP_DEBUG: true
      DEBUG: "nuxt:*"
      NPM_CONFIG_INTERACTIVE: "false"

    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Set up Node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: '12.20.0'

      - name: Install Yarn
        run: npm install --global yarn

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: yarn install

      - name: Build Project 1
        run: yarn build:parcel

      - name: Build Project 2
        run: yarn nuxt generate --dotenv .env.stage

I decided to go the direct approach and build the project on a self-hosted server with Github Actions. I'm stuck, because the Build Project 2 step doesn't produce any output (only 'Starting Nuxt configuration...') and fails after 30 minutes due to memory consumption. 'Started generation!' is never produced.
Starting Nuxt configuration...  
... [fails after 30 mins...]

On my local computer, as well as directly on the server, everything works well. But, of course, this is not an option because I need to automate it. This is how I do it on my mac or directly on server:
n use 12.20.0
yarn install
yarn build:parcel
yarn build:website

Which produces (what I expect):
Starting Nuxt configuration...  
Starting dynamic routes generation...     
Started generation!                                                                
ℹ Production build                                                    
ℹ Bundling for server and client side   
....

It seems like CI/CD is not even reaching my custom module ~/modules/dynamicRoutes, which is super wired and I don't understand the difference between ci/cd environment and the way I don it directly on the server... Do you have any ideas?
ps.: I tried github actions in cloud, jenkins and circleci - same problem...
